# Can a participial construction modify an adjective?

Tags: participial

> It was a very dark, cloudy night, and they were a bit late **arriving** at
>   Hagrid's hut because they'd had to wait for Peeves to get out of their
>   way in the entrance hall, where he'd been playing tennis against the
>   wall. (Harry Potter)

In the example, a participial construction seems to modify an adjective, late. Can a participial construction have the same function as a to-infinitive does, or does this have the role of something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why is that any different from the following?

> I was late getting to work this morning.
>
> We thought we got away without being seen, but were soon getting our comeuppance from Mrs. Ainsworth.
>
> I was crazy thinking I could pull the wool over their eyes.

All of these are normal, grammatical constructions. And so is Rowland's passage, even though it does run on.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the adjective *late* is modifying *arriving*. They were arriving, and they were late when doing so.

That said, a participle can indeed modify an adjective.

> The cheering yellow colour of daffodil buds promised an end to dreary February.